# Power Analysis for multivariate meta-analysis in R

Tags: statistical-power, meta-analysis

I am planning to run a multivariate meta-analysis with 11 studies and a total of 32 effect sizes in R. As this number is quite small, I would like to run an a priori power analysis to show that despite this quite low number of studies, the power is sufficient. I have found examples to run it in R, however, I assume that this is only for univariate meta-analysis: [dmetar](https://bookdown.org/MathiasHarrer/Doing_Meta_Analysis_in_R/power.html) and also [metapower](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/metapower/vignettes/Using-metapower.html). I am not quite sure, if I should use the 11 studies as command or 32 effect sizes. My meta-analysis is multivariate as I include studies with multiple endpoints and and multiple treatments.

it is quite strange that the results of these 2 packages are quite different.

My current code:

````
if (!"dmetar" %in% rownames(installed.packages())) devtools::install_github("MathiasHarrer/dmetar")
library(dmetar)
#install.packages(metapower)
library(metapower)
#install.packages(effectsize)
library(effectsize)

# using dmetar (aggregate effect size, assuming 30 participants in each group and moderate heterogeneity)
power.analysis(OR = 1.37, k = 11, n1 = 30, n2 = 30, heterogeneity = "moderate")

# same with 32 effect sizes
power.analysis(OR = 1.37, k = 32, n1 = 30, n2 = 30, heterogeneity = "moderate")

# metapower
# converting OR to d due to error message
mpower(effect_size = logoddsratio_to_d(OR= 1.37, log = FALSE), study_size = 60, k = 11, i2 = .5, es_type = "d")
```
````